# What is the minimal code I need to include from Webshim to get HTML5 date input to work?

Tags: javascript, html, date, cross-browser, webshim

I would like to get the HTML5 input date-picker to work on normally incompatible browsers, i.e. to have the look and functionaly as close as possible to [jQuery's datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

By including the libraries described in the documentation (inserted here at bottom) + the whole folder `shims` I get it to work as expected.

But as the `shim` folder contains many extraneous files - how do I understand which ones I should keep and which to throw away as there doesn't seem to be an option to custom build the Webshim library?

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-yepnope-custom.js"></script>  
<script src="js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
  $.webshims.polyfill('forms');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do this, I don't understand your exact problem here. The polyfiller.js will optimize the packages automatically for all browsers and webspace isn't that expensive (it's about 2mb on your server).

You can throw away:

The following directorys:
- FlashCanvas
- FlashCanvasPro
- jpicker

and all js files inside the shims folder, but form-*.js, dom-extend and es5.js

But again there is no need to do this. I don't understand why this is important. The only thing I do understand is to remove *.php from the directories (i.e.: in Flashcanvas...)

If you want to have as close as jQuery's datepicker you should set some conig options like startView, showOnFocus and so on for the date widget.

```
<style>
.date-input-buttons .step-controls {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<input id="date-1" type="date" data-date='{"startView": 2, "openOnFocus": true}' placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/VNuct/

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer + magnificient demo code!! The reason to exclude files is that I wanted to add webshims to a Rails app and as Rails is precompiling all files, the client load would be heavy. (Yes, I know there is a gem for this but I prefer adding the files manually.)

Comment: @alexander-farkas Could you comment on the remaining dependencies if you do the above reduction? I would like to use your polyfill, but i can't use GPL code or closed stuff. Is it possible to strip down the forms and forms-ext part so i only rely on MIT or Apache License?